# Unable to install python3 packages while creation of custom dataproc image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am following below link to create a custom image of dataproc-version 1.5.21-debian10
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images

according to this link if I try below customization script

#! /usr/bin/bash

apt-get -y update <-- This ends in error command not found

apt install python3-pip -y <-- E: Unable to locate package

python3.7 -m pip install numpy <-- /usr/bin/python3.7: No module named pip

instead if I try pip install numpy it installs the package in python2.7

Please suggest what can I do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008478/gcp-dataproc-custom-image-python-environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dataproc 1.5 images use Conda and Python 3 by default. To install packages in Conda environment you should use Conda's `conda` binary not system one:

```
/opt/conda/miniconda3/bin/conda install numpy
```

Note that it's discouraged to use Pip to install packages in Conda environment, but you still can do this if necessary:

```
/opt/conda/miniconda3/bin/pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use pip3 instead of pip to use the Python 3.7 env.

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: If apt-get -y update failed you have an issue with your Debian installation