# How to install optional components (anaconda, jupyter) in custom dataproc image

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, google-cloud-dataproc

To speed up my cluster instantiation time, I've created a custom image with all the additional dependencies installed using miniconda3 available for dataproc image 1.5.34-debian10. (I followed the steps here: [GCP Dataproc custom image Python environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008478/gcp-dataproc-custom-image-python-environment/57011301#57011301) to ensure I used the correct python environment).

However, when I start my cluster with *--optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER* my custom dependencies are removed and I'm left with a base installation of anaconda and jupyter. I assume the anaconda installation is overwriting my custom dependencies. Is there any way to ensure my dependencies aren't overwritten? If not, is it possible to install anaconda and jupyter as part of my custom dataproc image instead?

I've used the following command to create the custom image:

```
python3 generate_custom_image.py \
    --image-name test-dataproc-image-1 \
    --dataproc-version 1.5.34-debian10 \
    --customization-script ./pip-install.sh \
    --zone <my_zone> \
    --gcs-bucket <my_gcs_bucket> \
    --subnet <my_subnet> \
    --metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES="dask[distributed] dask-yarn==0.8 google-cloud-pubsub==2.4.1 kneed==0.7.0 google-cloud-secret-manager==2.4.0  pandas-gbq==0.15.0 pyarrow==3.0.0 leidenalg==0.8.4 cdlib==0.2.0 bigquery==0.0.12 google-cloud-storage==1.37.1 facebook_business pyemd==0.5.1 pysftp==0.2.9 gensim==4.0.1 wordcloud==1.8.1 spacy==2.3.0 https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0.tar.gz --ignore-installed PyYAML"'
    --no-smoke-test
```

Below is the content of my custom script pip-install.sh :

```
which python 

# Activate miniconda3 optional component.
cat >>/etc/google-dataproc/dataproc.properties <<EOF
dataproc.components.activate=miniconda3
EOF
export BDUTIL_DIR=/usr/local/share/google/dataproc/bdutil
bash /usr/local/share/google/dataproc/bdutil/components/activate/miniconda3.sh
source /etc/profile.d/effective-python.sh

# Now this is /opt/conda/default/bin/python
which python 
apt update
apt install python3-pip -y
python -m pip install --upgrade ${PACKAGES}
```

Comment: `apt install python3-pip -y` doesn't seem correct to me, you don't need to install it, you want to use `/opt/conda/default/bin/pip`.

Comment: There is a new reusable script for customizing Anaconda/Miniconda in custom images, you can give it a try https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/custom-images/blob/master/scripts/customize_conda.sh

Comment: Thank you, customize_conda.sh script worked. 

I'm not sure how to mark the question as answered, should I add an answer pointing to your comment instead?

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [customize_conda.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/custom-images/blob/master/scripts/customize_conda.sh) script is the recommended way of customizing Conda env for custom images.

If you need more than the script does, you can read the code and create your own script, but anyway you want to use the absolute path e.g., `/opt/conda/anaconda/bin/conda`, `/opt/conda/anaconda/bin/pip`, `/opt/conda/miniconda3/bin/conda`, `/opt/conda/miniconda3/bin/pip` to install/uninstall packages for the Anaconda/Miniconda env.